# Setting react-table page prop results in onFetchData always requesting that same page

Tags: reactjs, react-table

<strike>Suppose our container component accepts filter/sort/paging information in the querystring. This information is extracted from the URL in `componentWillMount` and set on the container's state. This state (let's say just the `page`) is then passed to our react-table instance as the `page` prop. We wire-up the `onFetchData` as `onFetchData={state => fetchData(state)}`. In our `fetchData` function we pull react-table's passed-in `page` and `pageSize` and slice our data, and then set it on our state. Next the render function fires again, pulls our state values and sets them on the table's props.</strike>

Sounds reasonable, however, it appears that this render > onFetchData loop happens without end until the browser fires a "maximum update depth exceeded" error.

We need to be able to set the *initial* page when we first load our component, but react-table doesn't appear to like this.

**Update**

This turned out to be a bug in react-table for which I've sent a PR:

Bug: https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/1230

PR: https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/pull/1231

Repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/50knlro2xn

Comment: Could you show what `onFetchData` looks like?

Comment: If all you want to do is set an initial page state why don't you just set the initial page number in state during `componentWillMount`. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/1o49po0rvl

Comment: @AlisonTinker Using `onPageChange` is really the answer (like you did in your example). I mean it's a _workaround_ but `onFetchData` should still pass the current state vs. the old state. Thanks, I will use that workaround for now. (Feel free to post as an answer.)

Comment: @JoshM. OK. I posted the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Per your update this looks like it could be the result of a bug. Here's a workaround for anyone who needs it:

If you want to set an initial page state you can set the initial page number in state during `componentWillMount`. See: [codesandbox.io/s/1o49po0rvl](http://codesandbox.io/s/1o49po0rvl)

Comment: Thanks. and a caveat to this workaround is that it will only work if your component which directly houses the react-table is the one who is managing the state where `page` is stored. E.g. if `page` is coming from props and passed to the table, then this won't work.